# OCaml signature dependencies error

Tags: compilation, dependencies, ocaml, signature

I have the following module signature `A`:

```
module type A =
 sig
  type exp =
    Int of int
    | Var of string
end;;
```

which I am able to compile in order to get `a.mli` and `a.cmi` files. However, if I define `B`:

```
module type B =
 sig
  val compute : A.exp -> A.exp
 end;;
```

running `ocamlc -i b.ml` produces the error `Unbound type constructor A.exp`. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OCaml gives you an outer module for free, corresponding to each source file. So you are defining a module type named A.A. Note that it's a module *type*, not a module.

It's possible your a.ml (and a.mli if you like) should contain just the following:

```
type exp = Int of int | Var of string
```

Then you can refer to A.exp from your b.ml file.

Also, note that a.mli is a *source* file. If you have an a.mli file, you need to compile it to create a.cmi.

Comment: Is it possible to do it with signatures somehow but avoiding `A.A`? I am trying to replicate signatures from some code for which I don't have the source, only signatures. And while your approach works for type definition like one above, I don't know how to do it for `val`.